# Why is my backgound image not showing up?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have put a image in the background but it is not appearing to me. I'm using bootstrap 5. How do I fix this ? I tried many things but none of them worked as I expected.

```css
html {
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Base Apparel coming soon page</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/808080" class="img-fluid"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">50%</div>
  </div>






  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. Please add an image from lorem pixel or similar

Comment: Remove the dot ( . ) in your url. Simply utilizing forward-slash ( / ) already means you're using a relative path. I also can't remember if the path needs to be inside either double or single quotes, but it always looked semantically better to me. Also, refrain from using the `<html>` tag as your selector. Instead use `<body>` or anything within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to place your background image in the `<body>` tag, not in the `<html>` tag, so

```
body { 
       background: url(./images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg) no-repeat center center fixed;
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `<body>` tag:

```
body { 
        background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080) no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
      }
```

Otherwise the background image shows after your content.

See [working example](https://codepen.io/cray_code/pen/ExvWmrE).